# How to see the text when using the RichText widget

Tags: flutter

I am reading the [Text Widget documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/text) for Flutter. I was wondering why I don't see the text on the screen using the `RichText` widget. When I use the `Text` and `Text.Rich` widget I am able to see the text right away but I can't see the text for `RichText`.

```
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Text Widget Documentation',
  home: Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Container(
      child: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
              text: 'Tutorial',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30, 
                  fontFamily: 'Roboto')
                  ),
          textScaleFactor: 2,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text must be inside children of TextSpan , so you can make more then one text thats why its called RichText, so you can make a long Text with different color or style.
this the link of flutter.dev : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html

```
RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 30, 
                          fontFamily: 'Roboto')
                          ),
                      textScaleFactor: 2,
                      children: <TextSpan>[
                       new TextSpan(
                                text: 'Your text here',
                                    style: new TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: widget.fontWeight,
                                    )), 
                        TextSpan(// othen then)

               ]))
```